# Как проверить соответствие имени файла маске?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть имя файла без пути и маска. Надо проверить, соответствует ли имя данной маске.

Маска может содержать:

- `?` - означает 1 любой символ
- `*` - означает 0 или более любых символов
- любые другие символы означают сами себя

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Задачу можно решить следующим образом (порядок проверок менять нельзя):

```
bool check(char *s, char *p)
{
char *rs=0, *rp;
while(1)
  if(*p=='*')
    rs=s, rp=++p;
  else if(!*s)
    return !*p;
  else if(*s==*p || *p=='?')
    ++s, ++p;
  else if(rs)
    s=++rs, p=rp;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Используемые переменные:

- `s` (`string`) - указатель на проверяемую строку (имя файла). В процессе сравнения сдвигается на проверяемый символ строки (префикс до него уже проверен).
- `p` (`pattern`) - шаблон, с которым сверяется строка `s`. В процессе работы сдвигается на проверяемый символ шаблона (префикс до него проверен).
- `rs` (`return in string`) и `rp` (`return in pattern`) - куда надо откатиться в строке и шаблоне. `rp` ссылается на последнюю проверенную `*`, `rs` на часть строки, которую эта звёздочка уже поглотила.

Обоснование алгоритма:

1. Единственный символ шаблона, которому может соответствовать пустая строка в имени - это `*`, поэтому эта проверка должна быть первой.
2. Если в шаблоне встретилась `*`, то мы можем заменить её на подстроку любой длины (от 0 до длины всей оставшейся части строки). Будем перебирать все варианты в порядке увеличения длины, т. е. пропускать на 1 символ больше после каждой неудачи.
3. Если в шаблоне есть несколько `*`, то при неудаче достаточно возврата к последней. Увеличение числа пропускаемых символов у более ранней `*` не может улучшить результат, т. к. подстрока между `*` уже соответствует участку шаблона, при этом величина сдвига уменьшиться не может, а её увеличение возможно и за счёт последней `*`.
4. Если строка закончилась, то это означает конец проверки. Результат соответствует тому, достигнут ли конец шаблона. Это объясняется тем, что единственный символ шаблона, который может что-то изменить - это `*`. Однако, количество пропущенных символов уменьшить нельзя, а его увеличение не сможет изменить результат (конец строки будет достигнут ещё раньше). Кроме того, в шаблоне не могут остаться только `*`, т. к. проверка конца строки делается после проверки на `*` в шаблоне.

PS: Этот алгоритм [используется](//forum.unrealcommander.net/viewtopic.php?p=6387#p6387) с 2010 года в [Ureal Commander](http://x-diesel.com/?7MtnP)'е.

Comment: Алгоритм у вас небанальный, С - язык небанальный, допускающий синтаксические фокусы. Зачем уродовать решение таким образом, сводя на нет всю читаемость ради эффектности?

Comment: @gbg, в коде нет ничего, сделанного исключительно ради эффективности. На мой взгляд, в такой форме он выглядит очень даже красиво. Что именно ты хотел бы поменять?

Comment: @gbg в первую очередь, я бы расставил скобки и избавился от оператора "запятая". Еще, было бы неплохо по-человечески назвать переменные.

Comment: прочитайте внимательно, я говорю о ковбойстве с языком (эффектности), а не об эффективности. Эффективнее было бы не садить здесь велосипед, а использовать регулярное выражение.

Comment: @gbg, не думаю, что запятая в таких простых выражения может помешать восприятию. Компактный код в виде условия и действия воспринимается гораздо лучше, чем раздутый в два раза за счёт скобок.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, мне понадобилось некоторое время, чтобы понять, где строка, а где маска.

Comment: @gbg, спасибо за напоминание, переменные переименовал и пояснил.

Comment: @VladD, да, поправил. На момент написания кода я вместо `pattern` подумал про `template`, поэтому вышло несколько непонятно.

Comment: @gbg, про эффектность не понял. Алгоритм не привязан к языку - его можно с некоторыми изменениями реализовать на любом языке. Про эффективность регулярных выражений - как минимум спорно. Нет причин, по которым они будут эффективнее. А для их использования надо ещё маску в регулярку преобразовать. Причём, с экранированием. Это что-то тоже нетривиальная задача.

Comment: @gbg, использовать регулярные выражения для реализации регулярных выражений (пусть и весьма ограниченных) это нетривиально!!! (а если у Вас их просто еще нет, то  их-то и нужно реализовать?)

Comment: @avp - большинство современных языков поддерживают обработку регулярных выражений. В итоге, мы либо вынуждены сидеть и доказывать безопасность потенциально опасного года, написанного через пень-колоду без комментариев (вон сколько объясниловки пришлось накатать автору), либо берем отточенный инструмент с автотестами. Если в реализации беготни по массиву (управляемой пользовательским вводом!) будет ошибка, мы рискуем огрести дыру в программе. Если то же самое будет при работе с регулярками - у нас просто будет криво работающий поиск.

Comment: @gbg, Вы бы хоть на метку (тег) вопроса посмотрели, а уже потом демонстрировали свой прагматизм.

Answer (score 2):

Маски - это последовательности символов и `?`, разделенные `*`. Например:

```
aa? * b?b * ?cc * ??d
```

По этому если написать функцию `partial_match`, которая сравнивает строку с маской до первой звездочки (с `aa?` или `b?b`), то задача сводится к следующему простому алгоритму:

```
match(name, mask) {
  // Матчим первую часть маски: "aa?"
  if (!partial_match(name, mask))
    return false; // Выходим если начало строки не совпало.

  while (*mask == '*') { // Перебираем остальные части маски: "* b?b * ?cc ..."
    ++mask;
    // Пробуем матчить строку со следующей частью маски,
    // до первого совпадения или пока строка не закончится.
    while (*name && !partial_match(name, mask)) {
      ++name; // Продвигаем строку вперед при неудаче.
    }
  }
  // Проверям что мы дошли до конца строки до конца маски.
  return !*name && !*mask;
}
```

На С++ это можно записать следующим образом:

```
class Matcher {
public:
    Matcher(const char* name, const char* mask) : name(name), mask(mask) {}

    bool match() {
        if (!try_partial_match())
            return false;

        while (*mask == '*') {
            ++mask;
            while (!try_partial_match() && *name != '\0')
                ++name;
        }

        return is_full_match();
    }

private:
    bool is_full_match() const { return *name == '\0' && *mask == '\0'; }

    bool patrial_match() {
        while (*name != '\0' && (*name == *mask || *mask == '?')) {
            ++name;
            ++mask;
        }

        return is_full_match() || *mask == '*';
    }

    bool try_partial_match() {
        auto tmp = *this;
        if (tmp.patrial_match()) {
            *this = tmp;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    const char* name;
    const char* mask;
};
```

[>>> Код полностью <<<](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63728a9e01a27f2b)