# Зачем нужны ветки else в языках программирования?

Tags: if, любой-язык, условия

Помогите разобраться. Допустим, есть такое условие:

```
function x (x) {

if (x <= 14){ 
return 'true';
}
else return 'false';
}

console.log(x(7));
console.log(x(714);
```

Понятно, что можно написать:

```
function x (x) {

if (x <= 14){ 
return 'true';
}
return 'false';
}

console.log(x(7));
console.log(x(714));
```

и этот код будет аналогично работать.

Другой пример: Пусть нам надо узнать, какое из двух чисел `k` и `n` больше. Мы сможем написать:

```
function greater (n, k){
   if (n > k ) return n +' greater then ' + k + '\r\n';
   else if (n < k) return k +' greater then ' + n + '\r\n';
   else return k + ' = ' + n;
}
```

Но мы также можем написать:

```
function greater (n, k){
if (n > k ) return n +' greater then ' + k + '\r\n';
if (n < k) return k +' greater then ' + n + '\r\n';
return k + ' = ' + n;
}
```

И все будет работать.

Зачем тогда нужны `else-if` и `else`, если первые можно заменить просто вторым `if`, а вторые - обычным `return` или кодом в теле функции ниже `if` с последующим `return` результата? Такие условия работают быстрее, чем обычные `if`? С ними просто удобнее читать код? Или есть другие причины?

Добавляю больше рассуждений если у вас есть один `if-else` вы можете заменить его на

```
if {
// обработка;
return res;
};
// обработка 2 ветки
return res;
```

Если условий много, то их обычно пишут через `else if`, но если мы не проварились в первый `if` то выполнение кода идет ниже в любом случае, то есть можно просто написать другой блок `if` ниже. Если ни одно из условий "каскада" не выполнилось, то ставят блок else который можно заменить на обработку и return "по умолчанию"

Так как в этом примере все условия разные, то и обработка при входе в них тоже должна быть разная, то есть код мы не дублируем.

Comment: _"и этот код будет аналогично работать"_ - а если сначала проверить?

Comment: If else можно заменить как if {return} return

Comment: "и этот код будет аналогично работать." - нет, при x <=14 код выведет true, потом false. В первом варианте выведет только true.

Comment: "If else можно заменить как if {return} return" - не всегда это возможно. Не все функции состоят из 3 строк, как у вас в примерах. Очень редко функции состоят только из if, часто нужно выполнить какие-то действия после проверки, а не просто выйти.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, вы правы, исправил.

Comment: Главное - поясните, разве наличие возможности писать ветвь `else` **обязывает** вас ее писать? Вы можете обойтись без нее? Обходитесь! В чем проблема? В конце концов, можно обойтись, скажем...  ну, без умножения — заменив его сложением. Так что, удалять его из языка? :)

Comment: @insolor Да, не всегда функции состоят из трех строк, но по идее всегда можно выполнить действия после проверки внутри блока if до return этого блока.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH в итоге придется копипастить одинаковый код внутрь блока if

Comment: @Harry Я не в коем случае не пытаюсь навести холевар. Мне просто интересно, зачем были введены эти конструкции. Пример с умножением и сложением показывает что с else код работает быстрее? Если использовать else или нет вопрос этетики, я бы сравнил его с арабскими и римскими системами счисления.

Comment: Просто ваши примеры, гм... очень специфичны. Это скорее просто примеры, когда можно обойтись без `else`, а не в общем случае. Как, например (беру другой пример :)), предложение обойтись без `pow` на том основанииb, что для `pow(x,2)` легче и проще написать `x*x`..

Comment: @Harry В том то и дело, что большенство случаев с pow таким образом замещать неудобно (при больших степенях). А случаи с if вроде бы все можно покрыть без else

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, а ещё всё можно покрыть без типов данных и циклов for и while (с goto). И вообще, про нормальные алгоритмы Маркова или машину Тьюринга слышали? Ими тоже можно всё покрыть (это не доказано, но опровергнуть невозможно).

Comment: @КириллМалышев Хорошо, добавлю общий вид своих рассуждений.

Comment: Так и с  `else` — *большенство случаев таким образом замещать неудобно* :)

Comment: @Harry Я имею в виду, что в случае с pow вместо pow (x, 10) у нас в коде будет x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x. Риск ошибится большой, да и читать такое неудобно. А в случае с else мы просто убираем else.

Comment: "Просто убрать `else`" в общем случае даст неверно работающий код. Если вы этого не понимаете - жаль...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483724/178988 - сможешь записать без использования else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if condition then
  ///
else
  ///
end
```

Эквивалентно (если у `condition` нет побочных действий)

```
if condition then
  ///
end
if not condition then
  ///
end
```

Очевидно, что во втором случае нужно писать больше, код становится более нагруженным. Становится сложнее разобраться, могут ли оба условных оператора выполниться вместе или выполняется всегда какой-то один. Придётся дважды вычислять `condition`. Если выражение `condition` вычислительно затратно, нужно тогда выносить его куда-то отдельно, а это ещё больше кода.

```
if condition1 then
  ///
elseif condition2
  ///
end
```

Эквивалентно

```
if condition1 then
  ///
else
  if condition2 then
    ///
  end
end
```

Считайте наличие `elseif` синтаксическим сахаром, который позволяет уменьшить вложенность условия.

Comment: Про побочные эффекты хорошее замечание, хотя `if condition` с побочками это ну, такое. Рано или поздно это может привести к проблемам. )

Comment: CrazyElf, да, но какой-нибудь fork или scanf типично могут там встречаться

Comment: Спасибо за довольно развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню, в `assembler` вообще нет конструкции `else`, там всё делается переходами условными и безусловными. Что-то типа такого на псевдокоде, настоящий ассемблер я уже слабо помню:

```
    проверить условие
    переход, если истина на метка1
    код, который нужно выполнить при невыполнении условия
    безусловный переход на метка2
метка1:
    код, который нужно выполнить при выполнении условия
метка2:
    дальнейший код
```

Так что как бы на нижнем уровне никакой `else` и не нужен. Но он всё-таки удобен, поэтому в языках высокого уровня он используется. Например, в случае сложного условия:

```
if условие1 и (условие2 или условие3) и не условие4
   код при выполнении условия
else
   код при невыполнении условия
```

Если бы не было конструкции `else`, вам бы тут пришлось повторять все условия:

```
if условие1 и (условие2 или условие3) и не условие4
   код при выполнении условия
if не (условие1 и (условие2 или условие3) и не условие4)
   код при невыполнении условия
```

И это бы часто приводило к каким-то ошибкам. Любая лишняя копипаста - повод для ошибок, принцип `DRY` придуман не просто так. Да, можно было бы сохранить результат проверки в отдельную переменную и проверять только её, это было бы короче, но зачем множить переменные и их проверки, если можно использовать `else`?

Comment: "Насколько я помню, в assembler вообще нет конструкции else" - более того, там даже if нет)

Comment: @insolor  jz je  вроде похожи

Comment: @Интик, это команды (одни из многих, к тому же jz и je - это одно и то же), с помощью которых реализуется if, но if как такового в ассемблере нет.