# inline if и тернарный оператор работает не как if. Почему так происходит

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, if, синтаксис, тернарный-оператор

Нужно написать алгоритм, который подсчитывает кол-во подряд идущих единиц.
Написал 3 наброска и столкнулся с тем что inline if && тернарный оператор работают иначе чем стандартный if в этом случае, может уже глаз замылился и я чего то элементарного не вижу =D, обычно всегда использую либо тернарный либо inline if и все работало...

убрал проверку

```
{
            if(counter > result){
                result = counter;
            }
            counter = 0;
        }
```

из else блока, чтобы просто было понятней, алгоритм я доработаю, мне просто интересно почему так синтаксис работает.

```
 const vector1 = (array) => {
    let counter = 0  // счетчик, его задача считать сколько подряд единиц идут друг за другом.
    let result = null // когда вместо 1 попадается 0 то счетчик обнуляется и значение сохраняется в result
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === 1) counter++; // если элемент в массиве равен 1, увеличить счетчик
        else result = counter; counter = 0; // если элемент в массиве не равен 1, то записать значение счетчика в result и обнулить счетчик
    }
    return result
}
debugger
console.log(vector1([0,1,1,1,1,0,1])) //выдаст 0, почему то проваливается в else ветку // не верно



const vector2 = (array) => {
    let counter = 0
    let result= null
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === 1) {
            counter++
        } else{
            result = counter; counter = 0
        }
    }
    return result
}
console.log(vector2([0,1,1,1,1,0,1]))// работает верно(с данным массивом)


const vector3 = (array) => {
    let counter = 0 
    let result= null 
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] === 1 ? counter++ : result = counter; counter = 0
    }
    return result
}
console.log(vector3([0,1,1,1,1,0,1])) // тоже самое что и с 1 вариантом
```

Спасибо.

Comment: `.... else result = counter; counter = 0;` - в таком случае, выражение `counter = 0;` выполняется **всегда**, т.к. к `else` тут относится только `result = counter;`. Это же JS, это Си-подобный язык... а не червяк какой-нибудь где блоки задаются индентацией... от того что ты записал два выражения в одну строку, они не становятся блоком. Блок в JS описывается фигурными скобками: `.... else { result = counter; counter = 0; }`

Comment: Точно, спасибо=D

Comment: Если хочешь ванлайн, то `const vector1 = arr => Math.max(...arr.reduce((r, v) => ((v ? r[r.length - 1] += v : r.push(0)), r), [0]));`, но это совсем ненужный мазохизм, на самом деле... код пишется в первую очередь для человека, а не для компа (иначе бы до сих пор опкодами программировали), он должен быть читаемым. А для минификации, есть автоматические инструменты.

Comment: Ну да, и читабельность упала. Ахринеть ты шаришь... круто. пойду про reduce почитаю, аж интересно стало =D.

Comment: KISS всему голова.

Comment: K.I.S.S. хороший принцип. Но как и любой принцип - он ставит целью ограничить. Упрощение восприятия и соблюдение правил, это только треть пути... вторая треть - снятие шор и понимание самой сути правил, того что их следует нарушать, и ситуаций когда это стоит делать. Если человек достигает 2/3 пути, это уже личный успех, т.к. на самом деле многие застревают на комфортной 1/3. Возвращаясь к правилам: в программинге (как и в любой другой деятельности) люди учатся на решениях типовых задач, чтобы затем остаток жизни решать нетиповые - из осознания _причин_ этого, можно извлечь колоссальную пользу

Comment: Сначала даже подумалось, не один ли и тот же человек вот это спрашивал - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1307413/195342 - зачем `else`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Глаз у вас замылился. counter не попадает под else без кавычек.
counter = 0 выполняется всегда.

```
const vector1 = (array) => {
    let counter = 0  // счетчик, его задача считать сколько подряд единиц идут друг за другом.
    let result = null // когда вместо 1 попадается 0 то счетчик обнуляется и значение сохраняется в result
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === 1) counter++; // если элемент в массиве равен 1, увеличить счетчик
        else result = counter; 
        counter = 0; // если элемент в массиве не равен 1, то записать значение счетчика в result и обнулить счетчик
    }
    return result
}
debugger
console.log(vector1([0,1,1,1,1,0,1])) //выдаст 0, почему то проваливается в else ветку // не верно



const vector2 = (array) => {
    let counter = 0
    let result= null
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === 1) {
            counter++
        } else{
            result = counter; 
            counter = 0
        }
    }
    return result
}
console.log(vector2([0,1,1,1,1,0,1]))// работает верно(с данным массивом)


const vector3 = (array) => {
    let counter = 0 
    let result= null 
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] === 1 ? counter++ : result = counter; 
        counter = 0
    }
    return result
}
console.log(vector3([0,1,1,1,1,0,1]))
```