# Не работает код, если выставить else if

Tags: javascript

По учебнику если несколько if, то второй if нужно записывать как **else if,** верно?
Но в моём коде, когда я пытаюсь следовать этому правилу, то есть на втором if пишу else if сразу после этого пропадает цикличность.

**Почему помеченная внизу строка кода работает лишь с if, а не с else if?**

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

let colors = [
{name:'red', interval: 1000},
{name:'', interval: 1000},
{name:'blue', interval: 1000},
{name:'', interval: 1000},
]

let count = 0;
let countColor = 0;

let go = setTimeout(function change(){
    
if(count === colors.length){
count = 0;  
}   

if(countColor === colors.length){   // Если вместо if, поставить else if, то цикличность пропадает
countColor =0;  
}
    
a[count].style.background = colors[countColor].name;    
go = setTimeout(change, colors[count].interval);
    
if(countColor % 2){
count = count + 1;  
}
countColor = countColor + 1;        
},1000)
```

```css
body{   
user-select:none;
}

.main{
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:200px;  
width:250px;
height: 100px;  
background: blue;
}

.item{
height: 100%;   
background: gray;   
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main">
<div class = "item" data-color='red'>1</div>
<div class = "item" data-color='blue'>2</div>
<div class = "item" data-color='orange'>3</div>
<div class = "item" data-color='gold'>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что в первом if у Вас count, а во втором - countColor. Else if нужен для работы с одной и той же переменной. А для разных переменных - разные if, никаких else. Иначе при срабатывании первого if до else дело не дойдёт, и нужные Вам действия с другой переменной программа не выполнит.

Comment: @humster_spb, спасибо за понятное объяснение, ставлю плюс!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Код читается сверху вниз**

---

`if`  код читает всегда, даже если их 99 штук, он все их прочитает, но если проверка `false`, блок кода не будет выполнен.

---

`else if` имеет ряд **особенностей**. Такое условие не может быть первым, оно стоит по середине между  `if и else` *(else  может быть опущен)*. Оно выполняется, если условие `if` **не было выполнено**.
[Пример работы  if/else/else if](https://jsfiddle.net/7oe3vcu1/3/)

Comment: Да блин, минусы-то за что, эх. Ради прикола что ли?

Comment: Возможно, за то, что на заданный вопрос это не отвечает? Впрочем, на него вообще вряд ли можно ответить...

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему вы считаете, что невозможно ответить на мой вопрос? Вот человек сверху ответил и я все понял =)
Чем ставить минусы, лучше бы дали адекватный ответ.
Типа: " Потому что в первом if у Вас count, а во втором - countColor. Else if нужен для работы с одной и той же переменной. А для разных переменных - разные if, никаких else. Иначе при срабатывании первого if до else дело не дойдёт, и нужные Вам действия с другой переменной программа не выполнит "

Comment: Один модератор ставит минусы прикола ради, другой закрывает все темы под надуманным предлогом. Найс живем.

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский, во-первых, лично я минус не ставил. Во-вторых, утверждение, что else нужен для работы с той же переменной - это бред. Ну и в-третьих, если я спрошу, почему 2+3=5 правильно, а если я заменю плюс на звёздочку, то уже нет, сможешь ответить?

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему бред? Приведите реальный пример кода, где в if проверяется одна переменная, а в else if - другая, не имеющая отношения к первой.

Comment: @humster_spb, а откуда вдруг взялось "не имеющая отношения"? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483724/178988 -пойдёт?

Comment: А я в ответе не говорил, что else нужен для работы с той же переменной, что за чушь, откуда такая гипотеза?

Comment: @WalkMess, а я и не говорил, что это ты сказал. А вот автор вопроса в соседнем комменте сказал: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EStLe.png.

Comment: @Qwertiy, оттуда, что в примере автора count и countColor - переменные, не имеющие отношения друг к другу: проверка одной на какое-то условие никак не связана с проверкой другой на какое-то условие. Именно поэтому их нельзя увязать через else if, потому что выполнение или невыполнение условия по одной переменной никак не связано с выполнением или невыполнением условий по другой.

Comment: @humster_spb, а где в комментарии автора про независимость переменных? Там просто про разные и я отвечал просто про разные.

Comment: Причём тут переменная вообще, капец. Это же условие, какая разница какая переменная...

Comment: @WalkMess, да вот именно, в условии же вообще что угодно может быть, а тут даже с переменными что-то выясняем... Ладно, держи плюсик.

Comment: Если  if  выполнится, то  else if  он даже читать не станет, даже если там правда или отрицание (!)

Comment: @WalkMess, читать будет, исполнять не будет. `if (true) { console.log(1) } else { let x; let x; }`. И не забывай звать того, кому отвечаешь, через `@`.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот тут никогда не углублялся, но насколько знаю, он не читает блок кода, или читает но просто не исполняет?

Comment: @WalkMess, ну чтобы что-то выполнять, надо прочитать весь код. Все early errors выдаются сразу и ничего вообще не исполняется. И даже если ошибки нет, могут быть последствия, например, всплытие переменных. Более классический пример: `var x = 10; ~function() { console.log("in", x); if (false) { var x } }(); console.log("out", x)`

Comment: "вот тут никогда не углублялся" - за это и минусы